# New rows are not being added under existing rows in new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy certain rows from one workbook to another, which I have working. However, it is not adding the new rows under the existing rows in the new workbook.

The source workbook has 10 sheets which all have different details in them, but each sheet is set out the same way i.e. column headings are the same. Each sheet has its own button which copies the Yes rows to the same destination workbook, all ending up on the same sheet. Column L is the Yes/No column. I can copy only the yes rows to the destination workbook, but they are being pasted on the top row, which overrides the rows that are already there. On the source sheet, I need to copy from row 14 and paste into the destination sheet at row 6. Any help with my code would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim outRow As Long
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, destWs As Worksheet

    Set sourceWs = Workbooks("SrcTest.xlsm").Worksheets("SRU 1")
    Set destWs = Workbooks.Open("DestTest.xlsx").Worksheets("All Data")

    outRow = 6

    For i = 14 To 200
        If sourceWs.Cells(i, 12).Value = "Yes" Then
            sourceWs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
            destWs.Rows(outRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            outRow = outRow + 1                 ' not adding new rows under existing rows
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Expected result is each time I click the button, all rows with a  Yes in column L are copied to the destination workbook under any existing rows. This needs to happen regardless of which source sheet I use (1 to 10).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping for every row(which is time consuming) you could just filter your data using the `"Yes"` criteria and copy paste just once like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim outRow As Long
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, destWs As Worksheet

    Set sourceWs = Workbooks("SrcTest.xlsm").Worksheets("SRU 1")
    Set destWs = Workbooks.Open("DestTest.xlsx").Worksheets("All Data")

    outRow = destWs.Cells(destWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next available row on destination workbook

    With sourceWs
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row on the sheet
        .Rows(13).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Yes" 'no need to loop, just filter the sheet with your criteria
        .Range("A2", .Cells(i, "M")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'copy the visible rows
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    destWs.Cells(outRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    destWs.Cells(outRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End Sub
```

My code assumes that you have data on the column A in both sheets.

Comment: thanks for this, yep I have data in columns A:M. I tried your code but got a runtime error '1004' - "We couldn't do this for the selected range of cells. Select a single cell within a range of data and then try again". Debug stops here: ```.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Yes"```

Comment: Do you have your headers on row 1?

Comment: on the source sheet, my headings are on Rows 12 & 13, and on the destination sheet it is rows 4 & 5. I changed the above code to ```.Rows(14)``` which is the first row where data is kept. I also changed the range to ```A14:M14```in ```.Range("A2", . Cells(I, Col))``` so it copied the whole row. This worked but it pasted the rows in the destination sheet without the source sheet formatting. Also on the destination sheet I have 500 rows already formatted i.e. borders, cell alignment and the yes rows were pasted at the bottom of these rows.

Comment: Your code pasted values, so did mine. Are there formulas on the source sheet? otherwise you can just `.Range("A2", .Cells(i, Col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=destWs.Cells(outRow, 1)` and delete the pastespecial line of code.

Comment: I have a formula in column A & B which I need the data it displays copied over not the formula.

Comment: @stacson76 I edited my code with the comments so it should do it fine now.

Comment: Ok, this is almost working, it is still pasting the yes rows at the bottom of the dest workbook which is the end of the formatted rows.

Comment: Where do you need the rows pasted?

Comment: the next blank row in the sheet, but the rows are formatted with borders & cell alignments which is why it is pasting at the last completely blank row...no formatting